# Spring Data ElasticSearch - cannot find GeoPoint field

Tags: spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hello Im trying to use ElasticSearch engine to sort entities by distance. I added 5 entites with `GeoPoint` value and now I'm trying to return it sorted by distance.

My model class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "location")
public class Location implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8120158607063175447L;

    @Field
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String title;

    @GeoPointField
    private GeoPoint location;
}
```

My sample test code

```
 SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withSort(new GeoDistanceSortBuilder("location").point(52.1,13.2))
                .build();
 Page<Location> places = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, Location.class);
```

- ElasticSearch Node 2.2.0
- Spring Data ElasticSearch 2.0.7
- ElasticSearch TransportClient 2.2.0
- Jackson 2.7.6
- Spring MVC 4.3.6

Stacktrace

```
Feb 18, 2017 12:25:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }{[I-X8ZtXlQ1OTOkozNrmpWA][location][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Stinger][172.17.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[{"_geo_distance":{"location":[{"lat":53.2,"lon":13.2}]}}]}]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:821)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:799)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.onFailure(TransportService.java:361)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:39)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort];
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:386)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.guessRootCauses(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.getCause(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:226)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException.writeTo(SearchPhaseExecutionException.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeThrowable(StreamOutput.java:560)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.writeTo(ElasticsearchException.java:226)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.ActionTransportException.writeTo(ActionTransportException.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeThrowable(StreamOutput.java:560)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransportChannel.sendResponse(NettyTransportChannel.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler$1.onFailure(HandledTransportAction.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.raiseEarlyFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:316)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.GeoDistanceSortParser.parse(GeoDistanceSortParser.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.addCompoundSortField(SortParseElement.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.parse(SortParseElement.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:836)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:652)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    ... 3 more

Feb 18, 2017 12:25:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.GeoDistanceSortParser.parse(GeoDistanceSortParser.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.addCompoundSortField(SortParseElement.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortParseElement.parse(SortParseElement.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:836)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:652)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I excluded some jackson project from spring data elasticsearch

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>com.google</artifactId>
                    <groupId>guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Generated mapping in ES Node

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/location/_mapping?pretty'
{
  "location" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "location" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "location" : {
            "properties" : {
              "geohash" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "lat" : {
                "type" : "double"
              },
              "lon" : {
                "type" : "double"
              }
            }
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used
`import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;`
instead `import org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint;`

**mic drop**

Comment: you can mark your own answer as the correct one then :)

Answer (score 2):

The relevant error is `failed to find mapper for [location] for geo distance based sort]`, which states that the `location` field is not having correct mapping required for a geopoint. 
You need the update the mapping for location field to geopoint type:

```
PUT <host_url>:<port>/location/mapping/<type_name>
{
  "<type_name>" : {
      "properties" : {
         "location": {
         "type": "geo_point"
         }
      }
  }
}
```

If you already have data in location field, then you need to recreate the index with correct mapping and reindex all data.

Comment: There is any way to make it using Java and annotations? I can try fix this manually but I think there should be way to make it by Spring Data ElasticSearch.